# How to replace pattern of string in r

Tags: r

I have a dataframe column which have pattern like

```
   | NA
```

I want to replace this and text after this with blank space.

```
  | NA | 0 | 4
```

So above string should be replaced by blank space.
I used following code.

```
  df$string <- gsub("| NA" , "",df$string)
```

But its nit workinh for the string after this pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
df$string <- gsub("\\| NA.*$" , "", df$string)
```

The pipe `|` symbol is a regex metacharacter (alternation).  So it needs to be escaped in order to match it literally.

The regex I used `\\| NA.*$` will match your desired pattern and anything following it to the end of the line, and will replace it with empty string.

Comment: I have other pattern like  | 0 | Recom : 0 | TGT : 0 Other. How can I remove above pattern till 'Other'

Comment: `gsub(".*Other", "Other", df$string)`

Comment: I have string before | 0 | but that string is not same in all rows. So how can I remove above pattern between 'dynamic string' and 'Other'

Comment: It's not clear what you want now.  You should open a new question.